# Using Protobuf, is it redundant to mark a property with [IgnoreDataMember]?

Tags: protobuf-net

Using protobuf-net, is it redundant to mark a property with `[IgnoreDataMember]`? Or is this the same as having no attribute at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be unnecessary for protobuf-net. IgnoreDataMember is useful for the DataContractSerializer because the default behavior is to write all publicly visible types. In that case, you have to opt out. For protobuf-net, you have to opt-in.

It does work, though, to override base class members and ignore a property that is included at the base level

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using ProtoBuf;

namespace ProtoBufTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test1 = new Test1() {Value1 = 5, Value2 = 10};
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(ms, test1);
                ms.Position = 0;
                var t = Serializer.Deserialize<Test1>(ms);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value written without DataMember: {0}", test1.Value2 == t.Value2));
            }

            var test2 = new Test2() {Value1 = 5, Value2 = 10};
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(ms, test2);
                ms.Position = 0;
                var t = Serializer.Deserialize<Test2>(ms);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value written with IgnoreDataMember: {0}", test2.Value2 == t.Value2));
            }

            var test3 = new Test3() {Value1 = 5, Value2 = 10};
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(ms, test3);
                ms.Position = 0;
                var t = Serializer.Deserialize<Test3>(ms);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value written with DataMember: {0}", test3.Value2 == t.Value2));
            }

        var test4 = new Test4() { Value1 = 5, Value2 = 10 };
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, test4);
            ms.Position = 0;
            var t = Serializer.Deserialize<Test4>(ms);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value written with IgnoreDataMember override: {0}", test4.Value2 == t.Value2));
        }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    internal class Test1
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public int Value1 { get; set; }

        public int Value2 { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    internal class Test2
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public int Value1 { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public int Value2 { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    [ProtoInclude(3, typeof(Test4))]
    internal class Test3
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public int Value1 { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public int Value2 { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    internal class Test4 : Test3
    {
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public new int Value2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

outputs:

Value written without DataMember: False

Value written with IgnoreDataMember: False

Value written with DataMember: True

Value written with IgnoreDataMember override: False